# Electron-builder: resource busy or locked. Failed to create installer

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have a little test electron app named hello world. I am trying to build it and generate a windows installer using electron-builder. My package.json is as follows.

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "productName": "Hello World",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Second attempt at an electron app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Computronics",
  "license": "MIT",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.hello.world",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `npm run dist` it outputs this.

```
> hello-world@1.0.0 dist C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world
> electron-builder

  • electron-builder  version=22.8.0 os=10.0.18362
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=9.1.2 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  ⨯ EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world\dist\win-unpacked\electron.exe' -> 'C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world\dist\win-unpacked\Hello World.exe'  stackTrace=Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world\dist\win-unpacked\electron.exe' -> 'C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world\dist\win-unpacked\Hello World.exe'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@1.0.0 dist: `electron-builder`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@1.0.0 dist script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\computronics\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-31T19_00_12_846Z-debug.log
```

The contents of the log file is as follows:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dist'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v12.18.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'predist', 'dist', 'postdist' ]
5 info lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~predist: hello-world@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: hello-world@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7-preview\preview;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\computronics\.dotnet\tools;
9 verbose lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: CWD: C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world
10 silly lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron-builder' ]
11 silly lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle hello-world@1.0.0~dist: Failed to exec dist script
13 verbose stack Error: hello-world@1.0.0 dist: `electron-builder`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid hello-world@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\electrontests\hello world
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dist"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error hello-world@1.0.0 dist: `electron-builder`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the hello-world@1.0.0 dist script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

After running `npm run dist` it creates a working .exe  in dist called `electron.exe`. This launches into the simple hello world app.

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling the dependencies, forcefully cleaning the npm cache and trying different versions of electron-builder.

Other information

```
OS: Windows 10
npm version: 6.14.6
node version: 12.18.3
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more than one reason for this error. Here are the ways you can get rid out of this error.

**Solution 1**. Close the `browser_broker` process

Open up the Windows task manager, find the running process named either `browser_broker.exe` or `Runtime Broker` and stop the process. After stopping the process, try building the installer again and it will work.

**Solution 2**. Kill the Build Tools Process

Open task manager and kill the `BuildTolls_Full.exe` process. Then Go to C:\Users<User Name>.windows-build-tools and open build-tools-log.txt with a text-editor and append the given and save the file.

```
Variable: IsInstalled = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There was no `browser_broker.exe` but I did close `Runtime Broker` and reran `npm run dist`. It still failed with the same error in vs code but when ran from `cmd.exe` it worked fine. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: It worked last night when I tried it but upon trying again this morning it fails with the same error. I tried the second solution but there is no such directory or file on my computer and no such process running. I am not sure why it would work then but not now. Any ideas? Thanks again for the original answer.

Comment: I think you should try re-installing the windows build tools because this is related to it.